# Representing a wave

Tags: waves, vectors, displacement

I don't know how relevant is asking this but We know that we represent waves by displacement, velocity etc.What about area vectors? I mean what about representing a wave by area vectors or even volume? Do such wave have a possibility of existence?

Answer (score 0):

At least mathematically you can have waves in arbitrary [tensor fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field), so yes. A [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) is a mathematical object that generalises scalars (numbers), vectors (displacement), and indeed area and volume forms. An example of a wave that is not just a simple displacement is a gravitational wave, which is a disturbance in the metric tensor field of space-time.